# Simple tensor manipulations in mathematica

Tags: tensors, algebra

I want to perform simple calculations involving kronecker deltas without specifying the dimension of the space I am in.

For example, I would like to automatically calculate (note the implied Einstein summation convention):
$$\delta_{i,j}\delta_{j,k}=\delta_{i,k}$$
and 
$$\delta_{i,i}=d$$
This is straightforward to do by hand, but the expressions involved are lengthy, so this is tediuous: e.g. I want to evaluate expressions sort of like the following, but a bit more complicated:
$$(\delta_{a,b}\delta_{c,d} \delta_{e,f}+3\delta_{a,d}\delta_{c,f} \delta_{e,b})(\delta_{i,j}\delta_{c,d} \delta_{e,f}+3\delta_{i,d}\delta_{c,f} \delta_{e,j})=?$$

I would think this is easy to do, but I cannot figure out how.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the new in M10 Tensor* function to do this, although it is a bit long-winded. First, lets define your identity matrix:

```
id = IdentityMatrix[d];
```

Next, we can represent your individual terms using [`TensorProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorProduct) and [`TensorTranspose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorTranspose). For example,

$\delta _{a,b} \delta _{c,d} \delta _{e,f}$:

```
TensorProduct[id, id, id];
```

$\delta _{a,d} \delta _{e,b} \delta _{c,f}$:

```
TensorTranspose[TensorProduct[id, id, id], {1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 2}];
```

and similarly for the others. Finally, we want to contract the expression:

```
res = TensorContract[
    TensorProduct[
        (
        TensorProduct[id, id, id] + 
        3 TensorTranspose[TensorProduct[id, id, id], {1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 2}]
        ),
        (
        TensorProduct[id, id, id] +
        3 TensorTranspose[TensorProduct[id, id, id], {1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 2}]
        )
    ],
    {{3, 9}, {4, 10}, {5, 11}, {6, 12}}
];
```

Unfortunately, [`TensorReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorReduce) is not able to simplify this further. However, we can make use of my `TensorSimplify` package to help out. Install the paclet with::

```
PacletInstall[
    "TensorSimplify",
    "Site"->"http://raw.githubusercontent.com/carlwoll/TensorSimplify/master"
]
```

and then load the package with:

```
<<TensorSimplify`
```

Then:

```
TensorSimplify[res]
```

> 6 IdentityMatrix[d]\[TensorProduct]IdentityMatrix[d] + 
>    d^2 IdentityMatrix[d]\[TensorProduct]IdentityMatrix[d] + 
>    9 d TensorTranspose[
>      IdentityMatrix[d]\[TensorProduct]IdentityMatrix[d], {1, 3, 2, 4}]

In terms of kronecker deltas, the above is equivalent to:

> $$d^2 \delta _{a,b} \delta _{i,j}+9 d \delta _{a,i} \delta _{b,j}+6 \delta_{a,b} \delta _{i,j}$$

Comment: excellent answer and a very useful package. Can I ask how you got from the Mathematica expression of the TensorSimplify command to restoring the subscripts in Kronecker deltas? I see the {1,3,24} in the end which indicates the ordering of the term proportional to 9d, but the other expressions are blank. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. The non-trivial part appears to be your package, which seems the most important. I was previously trying to do something involving replacement rules acting on symbolic expressions. But I think this will work.

Comment: @Konstantinos For a rank 4 tensor `T`, `TensorTranspose[T, {1, 2, 3, 4}]` is equivalent to `T`. So, imagine that there is a `TensorTranspose` wrapper on the other terms.